# Level Shifting Circuit to output 0.2V-4.8V

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, level-shifting, voltage-reference

Having a sensor's dynamic range from 4V - 10V, I am looking for a level shifting circuit using op-amp that gives me an output of 0.2V - 4.8V.  I have been looking through many design yet I could not get what I am looking for. Through hand calculation, I got a reference voltage of -12.286V but I am unsure whether it is correct or not. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How can you calculate a reference voltage without knowledge of a circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Since the scale (max-min) of your input is different to the scale of your output, this is not just a shifting problem but also a scaling problem. To both shift and scale using an opamp, the Differential Amplifier circuit is a great tool.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFfpOA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The defining equation for this circuit is:

\$V_{out}=(\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4})(\frac{R_1+R_3}{R_1})V_{in}-(\frac{R_3}{R_1})V_{shift}\$

So suppose you have a 5V rail available, and according to your question you want \$V_{out}=(\frac{23}{30})V_{in}-\frac{43}{15}\$ then you might choose values like so:

- \$V_{shift}=5V\$
- \$R_{1} = 1.5k\Omega\$
- \$R_{2} = 8k\Omega\$
- \$R_{3} = 4.3k\Omega\$
- \$R_{4} = 2k\Omega\$